# Using "order" property starts divs at the bottom and gradually rises as I add more

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As the title suggests I am messing around with `display: flex` and `order:`. When I start with my first ordered `div` (`order: 0;`) It will start at the top of my page. When I add in my first (`order: 1;`) it begins at the bottom of the page and so on so forth. What else is weird is that as I add more divs to the order it gradually moves them up on the page to where they should have originally started.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.lime {
  width: 100%;
  order: 0;
  background-color: lime;
}

.red {
  width: 50%;
  order: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.orange {
  width: 50%;
  order: 2;
  background-color: orange;
}

.teal {
  width: 100%;
  order: 3;
  background-color: teal;
}

.light_blue {
  width: 20%;
  order: 4;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.dark_blue {
  width: 60%;
  order: 5;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.green {
  width: 20%;
  order: 6;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box lime"></div>
    <div class="box dark_blue"></div>
    <div class="box light_blue"></div>
    <div class="box green"></div>
    <div class="box red"></div>
    <div class="box orange"></div>
    <div class="box teal"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I guess my question here is why is this happening and why is it only working as intended after I add my `.green {width: 20%; order: 6; background-color: green;}` at the end of my css?

Comment: your html/css is displaying as it should - the divs are in the `order` you specified. what are you expecting? If you don't have an `order` value on an element, the default is `0` so `.green` will display after `.lime` since lime is `0` and comes before `.green`. If you move `.green` before `.lime` in the html, it will display before `.lime`

Comment: @Brandon I don't understand your question. It works fine for me. If I add the elements lime and dark_blue, the lime element is on the top and the dark_blue is directly below (without any gaps)
What browser do you use?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then the snippet doesn't match the question, can that be right? Anyway, if one element has `order:1` and the other elements don't have an order, the one element will be displayed last because all the other ones have `order:0` by default. Does that explain what happens? If not, please provide more info on what you expected to happen. Maybe a mocked up screenshot.

Comment: If you were to code this, one order at a time, order 0 will start at the top of the page. But then adding order 1 it will start at the bottom and so on until I add order 6 where everything fits nice at the top of the page. What I expect to happen is everything to start at the top. http://imgur.com/a/ROyow this is what I get if I were to remove my order 6 and keep everything else the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is working as expected, (and it only works as intended after you set `order:6`, because until then the default value for that element was `order:0`)

Remember with [`order`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

> By default, flex items are laid out in the source order. However, the
>   `order` property controls the order in which they appear in the flex
>   container.

However you can simplify your use of `order`s in the code by just using the `order`s  4,5 and 6 in the same elements you are using it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
}

.lime {
  background-color: lime;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.teal {
  background-color: teal;
}

.light_blue {
  order: 4;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.dark_blue {
  flex: 0 60%;
  order: 5;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.green {
  order: 6;
  background-color: green;
}

.fifthish {
  flex: 0 20%
}

.half {
  flex: 0 50%
}

.full {
  flex: 0 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box lime full"></div>
  <div class="box dark_blue"></div>
  <div class="box light_blue fifthish"></div>
  <div class="box green fifthish"></div>
  <div class="box red half"></div>
  <div class="box orange half"></div>
  <div class="box teal full"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: While your edit definitely works, when I take away the last box, order 6 on the list in the CSS, i get a huge block of white space that shouldnt be there  http://imgur.com/a/ROyow like this between the lime and red/orange. and the white space right after the dark blue.

Comment: what are you trying to do after all?

Comment: I am just trying to order these colored boxes without getting that unwanted white space in between my order: 0 and order: 1 (lime and red). It seems if i do not have 7 items in my order list, there is unwanted white space, that I have no added myself just sitting in the middle of the page. Why is it that I need all 7 to do this?

Comment: It seems that removing the CSS and NOT removing the respective HTML ie: removing .green { } but NOT removing <div class="box green"> creates that unwanted white space. Was a good learning experience Ill give you the answer since your code did in fact work. Appreciate it.

Comment: I think OP wonder, why not giving that element a CSS rule but keep it in the markup, _creates an unwanted white space_. Well, as I answered, it is not an unwanted space, it is the 4:th element showing up exactly where it should, but it appears to look like a _white space_

Comment: Ya its true that, but as you can see OP figured it out something on it own, so when I was about to edit the answer (still trying to figure out what OP wanted at the time) OP figured it out apparently, Oh well :)